# Need to configure share cookie between edge and ie11 mode

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, admin

The site says to add such xml in order to configure the share cookies between edge and ie11 mode. But I don't understand where to add it, please tell me where to add it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-add-guidance-cookieshare

```js
<site-list version="1"> 
<shared-cookie domain=".contoso.com" name="cookie1"></shared-cookie>  
<shared-cookie host="subdomain.contoso.com" name="cookie2" path="/a/b/c"> 
</shared-cookie> 
<shared-cookie host="subdomain.contoso.com" name="cookie3" source-engine="MSEdge"></shared-cookie> 
</site-list>
```

Comment: "please tell me where to add it" - you haven't told us _anything_ about your website...

Comment: @Dai It's not about the site itself, but about sharing cookies between edge and ie mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first configure IE mode policies according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies). The steps are like below:

1. [Configure Internet Explorer integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration)
2. [Redirect sites from Microsoft Edge to IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#redirect-sites-from-microsoft-edge-to-ie-mode)

In the second step, when you [configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy), you can add the `<shared-cookie>` element in the xml file. For the xml file format, you can refer to [Enterprise Mode v.2 schema example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-schema-version-2-guidance#enterprise-mode-v2-schema-example).